# making a.active work with background image slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am having some troubles trying to get this to work, I'm new to javascript, and am pretty sure I'd need it for this.  I'd like to have my background image slide upon hover and stay active on its correct div when selected.  What I currently have html, css, and javascript wise works perfectly...javascript part is when user clicks on the div, a container opens up below it - that works as it should, however, I have no idea how to integrate giving the initial div a.active to stay active on that div rather than always going back into the center.  Any ideas, suggestions, and/or help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
Here is a jsfiddle of what is provided below: http://jsfiddle.net/mGQ8w/4/

This is what I got so far:

HTML

```
<div id="profile_selection">
    <a href="#nos_profiles" class="profile_selection">
        {ÑØ§}<br />Members
    </a>
    <a href="#registered_profiles" class="profile_selection">
        Registered<br />Members
    </a>
    <a href="#team_profiles" class="profile_selection">
        Team<br />Profiles
    </a>
    <div id="profile_selection_slider"></div>
</div>

<div id="nos_profiles" class="selection"></div>

<div id="registered_profiles" class="selection"></div>

<div id="team_profiles" class="selection"></div>
```

CSS

```
#profile_selection {
    width: 612px;
    height: 152px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 15px auto;
    position: relative;
}
#profile_selection a {
    width: 200px;
    height: 105px;
    padding: 45px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #333;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000, 0 28px 24px -24px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000, 0 28px 24px -24px #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000, 0 28px 24px -24px #000;
    float: left;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    color: #FFF;
    font: 24px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000, -2px -2px 2px #000;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
}
#profile_selection a:hover, #profile_selection a.active {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0;
    background: #222;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    color: #DF7401;
}
#profile_selection_slider {
    width: 64px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url(http://www.nosclan.net/images/Home/menu_bg_hover.png) no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 152px;
    left: 275px;
    z-index: 4;
}
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ #profile_selection_slider {
    left: 71px;
}
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ #profile_selection_slider {
    left: 275px;
}
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ #profile_selection_slider {
    left: 480px;
}
#nos_profiles {
    width: 950px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #222;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    border-bottom: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#registered_profiles {
    width: 950px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #222;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    border-bottom: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#team_profiles {
    width: 950px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #222;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    border-bottom: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.profile_selection').click(function () {
        var a = $(this);
        var selection = $(a.attr('href'));
        selection.removeClass('selection');
        $('.selection').hide();
        selection.addClass('selection');
        if (selection.is(':visible')) {
            selection.slideToggle(400)
        } else {
            selection.slideToggle(400)
        };
    });
});
```

LATEST UPDATE:::::

http://jsfiddle.net/mGQ8w/13/

Is it possible to make it where once a user decides to click a different div, the active class goes back to normal while the new selected div becomes active?  The way it is now, is that if you click on all 3, they all become active....I'd like it where only 1 is active - the one that a user clicks on....so if a user clicks on the NOS Members div, it becomes active, then if the user clicks on Registered Members, the NOS members is no longer active, but the Registered Members div is...

Comment: You missed out the jquery library.

Comment: this is not the answer, I just want to tell you to update your js fiddle link, and select JQuery under Frameworks and Extensions, so that it will not throw "$ is not defined" error on your fiddle.. thanks.. http://jsfiddle.net/mGQ8w/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the `active` class using `addClass`& can remove the remove the `active` class from previous selection using `removeClass`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.profile_selection').click( function(){
       var a = $(this) ;
       $('a.profile_selection').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
       var selection = $( a.attr('href') );
       selection.removeClass('selection');
       $('.selection').hide();
       selection.addClass('selection');
       if( selection.is(':visible') ){
           selection.slideToggle(400)
       }else{ 
           selection.slideToggle(400)
       };
    });
});
```

This need to be used along with the css changes provided by @N1ck as below

```
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ #profile_selection_slider, 
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(1).active ~ #profile_selection_slider {
    left: 71px;
}
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ #profile_selection_slider, 
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(2).active ~ #profile_selection_slider {
    left: 275px;
}
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ #profile_selection_slider, 
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(3).active ~ #profile_selection_slider {
    left: 480px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/mGQ8w/14/

Comment: That's almost it...the background image I have which is "#profile_selection_slider" needs to stay with the active class - how?

Comment: Do you want the slider to be active on the selected option and also should be present for the hover effect. That if 1st is selected, one is present below it, and if we hover 2nd another slider should show below it also? Is this the requirement?

Comment: Yes, having the slider background image that slides when you hover over either of the 3 div containers - upon clicking one of them, it all stays active and the slider background image stays underneath the div selected.  Then the other javascript is implemented which opens up a container once one of the 3 divs are clicked.

Comment: I guess N1ck answer is quite well :)

Comment: Actually, my mistake - that works if running the latest jquery library, I unfortunately am running 1.3.2 version - is there a way to make what Nick did work with 1.3.2?

Comment: Nvm, I was able to fix it ;)  Thanks to the code you helped me with Ashis and the css Nick provided.  I'll mark yours as the correct answer.  Thank you both for your time and help ;)

Comment: sigh...sorry to bother you all again - I thought I had it, but now how do I remove the active if user clicked on 1 of the other 3 divs?

Comment: Updated at the very bottom:

Comment: Perfect - Gracious ;)

Comment: You failed to mention the CSS change which was taken from my answer.

Comment: I mentioned it 8 comments up ;)

Comment: Was referring to @AshisKumar . Without the css I provided it doesn't answer the question fully.

Answer (score 2):

Give same rule to `.active` as you do for `:hover`  e.g:

```
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ #profile_selection_slider{
    left: 71px;
}
```

becomes

```
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ #profile_selection_slider,
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(1).active ~ #profile_selection_slider{
    left: 71px;
}
```

Then toggle the selected menu item with an `.active` class.

```
var menuItems = $('a.profile_selection');

menuItems.on('click', function () {
    var a = $(this),
        selection = $(a.attr('href'));

    menuItems.removeClass('active');
    a.toggleClass('active');

    ...etc
});
```

Here's a fiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/FbeFU/